# Check either if user has access to UNC path or is in an AD group from command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm writing a batch file to map two drives for a given account if the user has access. I don't want an error message to pop up if the user doesn't have access, I'd like it to fail silently and move on. All accounts have access to the first drive, so that one's fine, but only some users can access the second.

This is the command that actually maps the drive, variables are self-explanatory:

```
net use h: \\ipaddress\share "%password%" /user:%usern% /persistent:no > nul 2> nul
```

If I run this regardless of whether the user has access, a separate window opens with an error stating the user doesn't have access. `net use` **does not** set `errorlevel` if the user doesn't have access--it maps the drive but Explorer throws an error when trying to open it. The first drive checks if the user's credentials are entered correctly; `errorlevel` **is** set if credentials are incorrect.

The domain controller is not running AD Web Services, and the computer running the script does not have RSAT installed.

How can I check if a given user (credentials provided by prompts in the batch file) has access to a drive *or* is a member of an AD group so that I can determine whether to map a drive for that user inside a batch file?

Comment: What about using `runas` to start a new `cmd` instance under the said user credentials, then using `pushd` to access the UNC path, which sets the `ErrorLevel` if not accessible? could that work for you?

Comment: @aschipfl `runas` doesn't allow a password to be passed, only to prompt. I can't use that here; they enter the password separately and it needs to prompt only once. Great idea though, thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, true; perhaps the password can piped in: `echo P@ssw0rd|runas ...` (not sure if `runas` supports that); moreover, `runas` requires the user to be available on the host as well...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. First, get the distinguished name of the user account and store it in a variable. [`dsquery user`](http://ss64.com/nt/dsquery-user.html) is used to accomplish this.

```
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%f in (`dsquery user -samid %usern%`) do (
    set DN=%%f
)
```

Next, use [`dsget user`](http://ss64.com/nt/dsget-user.html) to list the groups a user is a member of and pipe it to a file.

```
dsget user %DN% -memberof > tmp.txt
```

Next, search the file for the name of the group using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html). `findstr` sets `errorlevel` to `1` if the string is not found, and to `0` if it is found. The output is piped to `nul` to prevent anything from showing in the prompt.

```
findstr /c:"H DRIVE MAPPING" tmp.txt > nul 2> nul
```

Since errorlevel is set, this is possible. `del` also sets `errorlevel`, so the check for the value of `errorlevel` must be done *before* deleting the file.

```
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo not in group
    del tmp.txt
    exit
)
echo in group
del tmp.txt
```

Comment: One of your constraints is that the user does *not* have RSAT installed - yet RSAT is required in order to run dsquery and dsget. :-/